# How to profile HP QuickTest Pro tests

Tags: vbscript, qtp, profiling

Is there any method to profile (measure execution time of code)  tests for QuickTest Professional? 
Or VBScript profiler, that can be applied for that purpose? 
Or at least approach and beacons how it can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTP has built in ***transactions*** for measuring time (see screen shot)

[image: transaction buttons]

If that doesn't fit your needs you can use `MercuryTimers` as [described here](http://automation-beyond.com/2009/08/18/anti-sleep-function/).

Comment: Thank you again :) Using that methods I need manually put transaction start and end points, but can I do it automatically? Because my script is large, with external actions and vbs libraries Maybe I can write some plugin that can insert calls for timing automatically, or work with MS Script debugger (which QTP use for execution & debugging I know)

Comment: @Vitaliy I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you look at the report you can see when each step was run so you can deduce the speed in which each step ran by subtracting the time from the time of the previous step.

Comment: Sorry, will try explain it. I have large scripts: driver script calls external action, it action calls procedures and functions. I want to run that test and get such results: function name - call times - execution times. Using "start transaction"  I need to manually insert  Services.StartTransaction statement in code, It may took a long time to do. So, I wonder if there any ready tool that can do profiling automatically with minimum of manual work?

Comment: @Vitaliy, I would suggest parsing the report (pragmatically) at the end of the run and extracting the data from there.